# How to maintain encapsulation when one object's death makes another object sick

Tags: c++, design-patterns, encapsulation

When an object `b` internally refers to and uses an object `a` it does not own, the death of `a` can make `b` sick.  Here is a minimal example to illustrate the point:

```
#include <iostream>

const int my_int = 5;

class A {
  private:
    int n_;
  public:
    int n() const { return n_; }
    A(int);
};

A::A(int n__) : n_(n__) {}

class B {
  private:
    const A *ap_;
  public:
    int m() const { return 1 + ap_->n(); }
    explicit B(const A *);
};

B::B(const A *const ap__) : ap_(ap__) {}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Will put an unnamed A on the heap.\n";
    A *const p = new A(my_int);
    std::cout << "Have put an unnamed A on the heap.\n";
    std::cout << "p->n() == " << p->n() << "\n";
    B b(p);
    std::cout << "b. m() == " << b. m() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Will delete  the unnamed A from the heap.\n";
    delete p;
    std::cout << "Have deleted the unnamed A from the heap.\n";
    std::cout << "b. m() == " << b. m() << "\n"; // error
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, one could fix this by letting `b` keep a copy of `a` rather than a pointer to it, but suppose that `b` prefers not to keep a copy (because `a` occupies a lot of memory or for some other reason).  Suppose that `b` prefers merely to refer to the existing `a`.  When `a` quietly dies, `b` never notices.  Then, when `b` tries to use `a`, unpredictable behavior results.

On my computer, the example's output happens to be this:

```
Will put an unnamed A on the heap.
Have put an unnamed A on the heap.
p->n() == 5
b. m() == 6
Will delete  the unnamed A from the heap.
Have deleted the unnamed A from the heap.
b. m() == 1
```

However, on your computer, the result might be a segfault or who knows what.

My example's trouble seems to lie in that the example indirectly breaks the encapsulation of `b`, leaving it to the programmer to remember that the continued validity of `b` depends on the continued existence of `a`.  When the programmer forgets, the program breaks.  The harassed programmer thus is required to keep `b` in mind whenever he works on `a` *even though the type A as such does not care about the type B*.  As you know, object-oriented programmers prefer not to have to keep such trivia in mind if they can help it.

I meet this problem under more complicated guise now and then while programming.  I have met it again today.  One feels that, somehow, there should exist an elegant design pattern to maintain the proper encapsulation of `b`, to transfer from the programmer to the compiler the responsibility of remembering `b`'s dependence on `a`'s existence -- and that the pattern fundamentally should involve something less elaborate than smart pointers and full-blown reference counting.  However, maybe I am wrong.  Maybe this is exactly what smart pointers their reference counting are for.  Either way, I know neither the right pattern to apply against the problem nor the best way to fix the code.

If you do know, would you tell about it?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1351283/1275653) is the most nearly related answer I notice already on Stackoverflow; but, besides using one or two words I do not understand, that answer does not seem to answer this question, anyway.

(My compiler still does not happen to support C++11 very well, but if C++11 brings a feature specifically meant to address my problem, then of course I should be interested to learn of it.  Admittedly however, my question mainly concerns OO/scoping fundamentals.  The question is even more interested in the underlying design pattern than in this or that new feature of the latest compiler.)

**NOTE TO THE READER**

Some good answers have graced this question.  On Stackoverflow, as you know, the asker has the responsibility to *accept* the best answer so that (when you read this months or years later) you will not have to search for it.

However, it is the combination of two answers that best answers this question.  You should read both:

- @MatthieuM.'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543871/1275653) re shared ownership and the observer pattern; and
- @JamesKanze's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543914/1275653) re why and when the observer pattern may be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two particular solutions:

- shared ownership
- observer pattern

In the shared ownership solution, the lifetime of `a` is determined by a counter of the number of *owners*, only when there is no owner any longer does `a`'s lifetime come to an end. This is typically implemented using `std::shared_ptr<A>`.

In the observer solution, when `a` is passed to `b`, `a` memorizes that `b` holds a reference to it. Then, when `a` dies, either it notifies `b` right away or leave a "token" behind for `b` to be notified at the next access attempt.

The direct notification is usually handled by maintaining a list of the current referrers and calling to each of them at destruction time (so they can erase their reference). It is the typical observer pattern.

The indirect notification is usually handled by having a proxy object to go through to get to `a`. When `a` dies the proxy is notified (O(1)) and when `b` attempts to access `a` it must pass through the proxy. There are various difficulties in implementing this on your own, a better approach is therefore to use standard facilities: `std::shared_ptr` this time combined with `std::weak_ptr`.

Finally, these solutions are not equivalent.

- shared ownership implies that `a` cannot die whilst `b` lives while an observer scheme allows `a` to die first
- direct notification lets `b` react immediately about `a`'s death, but at the same time may make the program more brittle (during `a`'s destructor execution, you should not throw any exception)

Choose your own poison :)

Comment: You shouldn't allow exceptions to propagate out of a destructor in any case.  As you say, the solutions are not equivalent.  Which one is appropriate depends on the program logic.  (In my own experience, it's about 5 to 1 in favor of the observer pattern.  But this doubtlessly depends on the application domain.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: The problem is not just *propagating*. When the destructor is executed during stack unwinding, `terminate` is called the moment you try to `throw`, not if another exception gets out the destructor.

Comment: It shouldn't, unless C++11 has changed something.  You can still throw an exception in a destructor, as long as it is caught in the destructor, and doesn't propagate out.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on why the first object is being deleted.  If it's
just because someone thinks no one is using it, then you may be
able to avoid the problem with smart pointers—you still
have to watch out for cycles, but if the reason for using
dynamic allocation is simply to avoid overly expensive copies,
the object probably just p ure data, and doesn't have any
pointers, so you're safe.

Far more often, of course, the reason why the object is being
deleted is because the program logic requires it, and deferring
the deletion by means of some sort of smart pointer will break
the program logic.  In such cases, the class having a pointer to
the object must be notified that the object has been deleted, an
act in consequence.  In this case, the observer pattern is the
standard solution; your object `b` would register with the `A`
object, be informed of its demise, and do whatever it had to do
in consequence.  If we take the simple case where your `B` class
is `Session`, and the `A` class is `Connection`.  If the actual
connection drops, the `Connection` class will be informed, and
self destruct.  When doing so (in its destructor), it will
inform all of the objects registered with it.  If you're on a
server, the `Session` class will probably log the problem and
self-destruct itself—a dropped connection terminates the
session.  In a client, however, the `Session` class may try to
create a new `Connection`, and only abort the session if that
fails.

Comment: Regrettably, one cannot *accept* two answers, for this answer also deserves to be *accepted.*

Answer (score 3):

The smart solution is to use smart pointers, if you really need to keep just one object, not multiple copies!

C++11 gives you [multiple choices](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to choose from:

- `std::unique_ptr`
- `std::shared_ptr`
- `std::weak_ptr`

In your case, I think you need the second one: `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: +1.  Do you also happen to know of another, lighter, reasonable design pattern to address my problem?  To put the question in other words, how did C++ programmers address the problem before 2003 and TR1?  In one instance a decade ago, I addressed it by implementing my own reference-counting pointer, because I could think of nothing else to do!  Of course, now I would follow your suggestion and use `std::shared_ptr`.  What I was really wondering today though is whether there did not exist some lighter solution.  (It seems that you imply that the answer probably were no.)

Comment: In most cases, I expect that using `shared_ptr` will break the program logic.  Presumably, whoever is deleting the object is doing so because it must be deleted at that particular point in time.

Comment: I might add that `shared_ptr` is one of the most dangerous tools around _if_ the pointed to object has any real behavior, which might risk `this` escaping from a member function, and being used to create a new `shared_ptr`.  (It's also a problem if the object has pointers to other objects, which might point back to it.  `std::shared_ptr` doesn't handle cycles.)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you're looking for is "if you own an object, don't give away non-owning references to it and then destroy it." I don't think it has a better name but it's really just good C++ etiquette. If you give away a pointer to an object that can keep hold of it, you need to know that that object may rely on the pointer staying valid. In this situation, you simply ensure the lifetime of your object outlives the lifetime of the non-owning object.

If you're passing into a function, and you can assume that function doesn't make use of global state, then I wouldn't worry about it - once the function returns, you should assume it is done with that pointer.

The real way to stop worrying about this is, as Nawaz said, to use smart pointers with proper ownership semantics. If you want to transfer ownership to another object, use a `std::unique_ptr`. If you want to share ownership, use a `std::shared_ptr`. If you want to use a non-owning raw pointer, I'm not going to say *don't*, but at least know the problems it may cause.

---

To simply avoid accidentally deleting the object too early, you *could* do the following:

```
const std::unique_ptr<A> p(new A(my_int));
B b(p.get());
// the A object will be destroyed at the end of the current scope
```

Here you don't have the (very minimal!) overhead of a `std::shared_ptr`. I'm not sure I'd really recommend it. It's much more preferable to go full-smart than semi-smart. The `const std::unique_ptr` has similar ownership semantics to a `boost::scoped_ptr`: it says "I own this and nobody else ever will." The difference is that you won't be able to call `reset` on this `const std::unique_ptr` as you would on a `boost::scoped_ptr`.

Comment: Right.  What I want is for the compiler, in one way or another, to help me with the "don't destroy it" part, so that I don't have to rely upon me not to forget.  In other words, I want encapsulation without copying the object.  One suspects that you are correct when it comes to the `std::shared_ptr`, though I was hoping for something lighter!